# In UDP, destination

Tags: udp, ip

In UDP, destination IP and destination port number are used to demultiplex the packets, but in TCP destination IP, source IP, destination port number and source port numbers (4-tuple) all needed to distinguish between the connections why reasoning for this usage.

Comment: Remember to mark a reply as "the answer" to your question, if it gives you the info you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely due to the fact that UDP is connectionless - it doesn't *have* any concept of connections, so it is only the destination address that matters.